# What are the differences between Visual Studio "Ultimate" and "Premium"?

Tags: visual-studio

Whats the "real world" difference between Visual Studio Ultimate and Premium?

Comment: Are the additional features fully fledged, or are they the typical "throw it against the wall to see if it sticks" stuff?

Comment: so.. Why is this closed as offtopic when there are many other posts like this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470057/do-i-need-to-buy-visual-studio-professional

Comment: Please vote to reopen if you would like to see an answer to this question.

Comment: Which version Visual Stuido ?

Comment: [https://archive.org/details/vs-2013-compare-versions](https://archive.org/details/vs-2013-compare-versions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### IntelliTrace

Historical debugging can be very useful

Ultimate also has additional architecture and testing features.

Answer (score 14):

The comparison table [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) summarises the differences between Ultimate and Premium - not the inclusion of some extra features at Ultimate level (e.g. lab management and full architecture and modelling model).

Biggest difference is the crippling *price* of Visual Studio Ultimate.

Comment: Just to be aware, the link is no longer active since the release of VS2015 has redirected this page

Comment: Now, http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-with-msdn-overview-vs#AdditionalPageSections_1 is for ***VS 2017***